# What's wrong with solution about $\sin^2(x), \cos^2(x), \sin(x)\cos(x)$ being sides of triangle

Tags: probability, functions, trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification

[image]

Above are the question and correct solution. However I would like to know what mistake did I make in my own unfinished solution:

It's symmetric so we can take $0<x<45^{\circ} \implies 0<\tan(x)<1$. The triangle can't exist if and only if
$$\cos^2(x)>\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\iff \tan^2(x)+\tan(x)-1 < 0$$
$$\iff \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}< \tan(x) < \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: You have to combine the inequalities to $0< tan(x) < \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but other than that this is correct because $\arctan(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) = \frac{\arctan 2}{2}$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ok, actually, I implicitly meant that. Ok, thank you, I finished it.

Comment: There's a double angle formula for $\tan$. Applying that is basically the equivalent of applying the double angle formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ like they did in the official solution, just at a different point in solving process. This is also how you can derive the $\tan$ double angle formula from the $\sin$ and $\cos$ ones.